# Merging two pandas DataFrame the result is empty in Airflow (locally it works)

Tags: python, pandas, airflow

I have 2 dags each one sends a json to the Xcom in Airflow.

The last dag takes each json turn it into a pandas df and merges it.

For some reason, it's not working and I'm trying to keep calm.

```
#Snowlflake (Xcom)
snowflake_dict = [{"table_name" :"leads" ,"last_update_date_snow" :1699269594000}
                  ,{"table_name" :"loan" ,"last_update_date_snow" :1698966458752}]
# mySQL (Xcom)
mysql_dict = [{"table_name" :"leads" ,"last_update_date_my" :1699341986000}
              ,{"table_name" :"loan" ,"last_update_date_my" :1699275608110}]

df_snowflake = pd.DataFrame(snowflake_dict)

df_mysql = pd.DataFrame(mysql_dict)

#simple shit
merge_df = pd.merge(df_snowflake, df_mysql, on='table_name', how='inner')
```

This is the relevant dag:

```
merge_last_update = PythonOperator(
    task_id='merge',
    python_callable=merge_last_update,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag
```

**The error I see in Airflow:**

File "/usr/local/airflow/dags/resources/Snowflake_sync/merge_last_update.py", line 31, in merge_last_update
merge_df = pd.merge(df_snowflake, df_mysql, on='table_name', how='inner')
File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py", line 110, in merge
op = _MergeOperation(
File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py", line 703, in **init**
) = self._get_merge_keys()
File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py", line 1162, in _get_merge_keys
right_keys.append(right._get_label_or_level_values(rk))
File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1850, in _get_label_or_level_values
raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'table_name'

Comment: Try it: merge_df = df_snowflake.merge(df_mysql, on='table_name', how='inner')

Comment: Tried it.
Doesn't work ;(

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches that can be taken when merging multiple DataFrames on the Apache Airflow (You can adjust these to your code):

**A (Useful for "for loop").**

1. Create an empty list to place the DataFrames: all_dataframes = []
2. Add the DataFrames that you have using pandas' append function to the all_dataframes: all_dataframes.append(df)
3. Merge all the DataFrames in the list using pandas' concat function: final_dataframe = pd.concat(all_dataframes, ignore_index=True)

**B.**

1. Add the relevant DataFrames to a list where you will place all of the DataFrames: all_dataframes = [block_bid_df, block_offer_df, price_independent_bid_df, price_independent_offer_df]
2. Note that you should import reduce function from functools: final_df = reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, on=['Date'], how='outer'), all_dataframes)